# find command with variable

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a file which contain a build version in a folder. I have assigned that version stored in a file but somehow I couldnt find it with if I use variable

```
[root@centos deploy]# VERSION=1234.56789
[root@centos deploy]# echo $VERSION
1234.56789
[root@centos deploy]# find . -name '*$VERSION*'
[root@centos deploy]# find . -name '*1234.56789*'
./abcd_1234.56789_apr13.rar
[root@centos deploy]# find . -name '*`$VERSION`*'
[root@centos deploy]#
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables won't expand when put inside single quotes, you need to use double quotes:

```
find . -name "*$VERSION*"
```

Comment: Thank you , its working. in 9 min it will be accepted.

Comment: By convention, environment variables (`PATH`, `EDITOR`, `SHELL`, ...) and internal shell variables (`BASH_VERSION`, `RANDOM`, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be lowercase. Since 
variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.